# Javascript array.shift() is removing all the elements at once

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is the array returning it as if all of the array.shift()'s were performed first, then the console.log()'s?

Here is my code:

```
var y = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
y.shift();
console.log(y);
y.shift();
console.log(y);
y.shift();
console.log(y);
```

I would expect this to be the output:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
[3,4,5,6]
[4,5,6]
```

But this is what I am currently getting:

```
[4,5,6]
[4,5,6]
[4,5,6]
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: See also: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/5923139)

Comment: I am running this within the script section of an HTML file using Electron if that is somehow relevant, since this doesn't seem to be happening when running this in "Tryit Editor".

Comment: Read the answers on the linked questions; `console.log` in the browser console evaluates the array lazily, which means only the final value is shown.

Comment: Pretty sure @Aplet123's link is the answer. Running this code in my browser's dev tools section shows it correctly. If you want to be sure, toss in a `debugger;` before the first `y.shift()` and then step through it to verify that the shift function is working correctly

Comment: @Aplet123 That certainly answers the question on why it is being printed that way. Unfortunately I was hoping that was the issue I was running into on a larger problem, evidently not. Thank you very much for your help.